# React Native avoid FlatList re-render when I select one item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

### DESCRIPTION

I am implementing an Image Picker but having some performance issues that I need to solve...
In my component, the user can select multiple items (images) from his gallery (the FlatList renders all images in his gallery). When some item is selected, it is added to the array of selected images (it is a state).

### PROBLEM

As the array is stateful the component will re-render... but I only need to re-render the image that was clicked by the user (because then a badge will be showed inside it) not the full FlatList.

Any ideas how to do this?

### CODE

```
const keyExtractor = ({ uri }) => uri;

class ImagePicker extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
  };

  loading = false;
  cursor = null;

  state = {
    images: [],
    pickedImages: [], // <----------------------------------
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages();
  }

  getImages = async (after) => {
    if (this.loading) return;

    this.loading = true;

    const results = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      first: 20,
      after,
      sortBy: MediaLibrary.SortBy.creationTime,
    });

    const { assets, hasNextPage, endCursor } = results;

    this.setState({ images: this.state.images.concat(assets) }, () => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.cursor = hasNextPage ? endCursor : null;
    });
  };

  getNextImages = () => {
    // If there are no more pics to get, do nothing
    if (!this.cursor) return;

    /*
      If we don't check the above condition,
      once we reach the final of the camera roll,
      the beginning will be loaded again
    */

    this.getImages(this.cursor);
  };

  pickImage = (image) => {
    /*
      This method returns a boolean that indicates 
      if it was possible to select the image tapped by the user 
    */
    const { pickedImages } = this.state;

    // If the element is already in the list remove it
    if (isElementInList(image, pickedImages)) {
      this.setState({
        pickedImages: removeListElement(image, pickedImages),
      });

      return false;
    }

    // Do nothing if the user has already selected MAX_ALBUM_LENGTH images
    if (pickedImages.length === MAX_ALBUM_LENGTH) return false;

    // If the image is not currently picked, add it to the list of picked images
    if (!isElementInList(image, pickedImages)) {
      this.setState({
        pickedImages: [...pickedImages, image], // <----------------------------------------
      });

      return true;
    }
  };

  renderItem = ({ item: { uri }, size, marginTop, marginLeft }) => {
    const style = {
      width: size,
      height: size,
      marginLeft,
      marginTop,
    };

    const { pickedImages } = this.state;

    return (
      <Item
        uri={uri}
        onPress={this.pickImage}
        pickedImages={pickedImages}
        style={style}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      theme: { colors },
      handleClose,
      handleConfirm,
    } = this.props;

    const { images, pickedImages } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <View style={styles.topButtonsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            style={styles.topButton}
            onPress={handleClose}
          >
            <Icon
              name="ios-close"
              type="ionicon"
              color={colors.black}
              size={40}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {pickedImages.length > 0 && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              style={styles.topButton}
              onPress={handleConfirm}
            >
              <Icon
                name="ios-checkmark"
                type="ionicon"
                color={colors.black}
                size={40}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
        <Grid
          data={images}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          initialNumToRender={20}
          removeClippedSubviews
          onEndReached={this.getNextImages}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Pd: The component "Grid" is just a FlatList wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to do was moving the items from PureComponent to Component and modify the shouldComponentUpdate as follows:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // If the state "isSelected" has changed then update
  return nextState.isSelected !== this.state.isSelected;
}
```